Why is the "observe how bravely I conceal..." phrase from "Candide" notated this way?
I'm referring to the subject matter as it appears in "Glitter and be Gay," plus the corresponding material in the overture.
I imagined — just by listening — that the counting would be something like this:

But what's apparently actually written in the score (sorry, I don't have one at hand — this is gleaned from the least dubious score reduction videos I could find on the web) is this apparently polymetric figure:

and similarly for the material used in the overture, which is written

I'm confused as to why this is so. I find it hard to get that sense of hemiola in the bottom register when the notation is so written (even if it's audibly obvious) and I don't see how this improves the clarity of the written score.
The chief possibility I'm considering is self-error. I asked a musician with orchestral experience about this and he answered me, "Why does it matter? The phrase is played the same regardless." Perhaps I have attached way too much importance to the written meter, or perhaps I have completely mis-parsed the phrase in my mind?
Feedback on question-asking and mental model are very welcome.
Supplement to the accepted answer
Lyrics added to the counting I thought up:

Lyrics over the canonical meter, with the rhythm of the text bolded:


All this work just to get the "-ceal" in "conceal" on Beat 1?

Without the original score — or "official" reduction — any answers will be educated guesses.

Look at the text.  It is in iambic tetrameter:
.  /     .    /   . /  .  /
Observe how bravely I conceal

  .   /   .     /   .    /   .  /
The dreadful, dreadful shame I feel.

Using the second example in the question, the eight accents fall on

beat three of bar 8
the downbeat of bar 9
beat three of bar 9
the downbeat of bar 10
beat three of bar 10
beats one and two of bar 11 (which is in 5/8)
beat four of bar 11
the downbeat of bar 12

If we try to use 3/4 meter, the accents fall first on beat 3, then on beat 2, then on beat 1.  Now it's true that the bass line supports these accents, but, as with any good vocal composer, Bernstein privileges the text and its duple meter, so we end up with 12 against 8 with three groups of 4, instead of four groups of 3 against 2.
That should be sufficient to answer the question: Bernstein employs the traditional metrical approach to text setting, placing the accented syllables of the poetic meter on the strong beats of the musical meter.
More generally, though, I have to say that I got to know the overture long before I knew the aria, and the passage in question always seemed to me as basically a duple meter with three note groups in the melody and a cross rhythm in the bass for the sake of interest.  I suppose the tendency to hear it as I did or as you did will depend on the performance: if it is played with an obvious accent on the downbeats, the tendency to hear a triple meter will be less; if the performance is more even then the listener may infer accents on the higher pitches and therefore hear a triple meter.  (I should add that the recording through which I learned the Candide overture was conducted by Bernstein, so he may have taken pains to bring out the duple meter.)
Also note that the duple meter is more in line with the meter that precedes it: it is slightly faster, whereas if we took the bass line as the principal meter it would be somewhat slower.  Furthermore, the tempo remains the same after the cross rhythm ends, but only if we take the duple meter as primary.
In short, the other answers are correct to note that cross rhythms of this sort are an important element of Bernstein's style, but the fact that the barring reflects the poetic meter, along with the tempo relationships with the preceding and following musical material, suggests that the duple meter was primary in Bernstein's mind when he composed the piece.

Interesting! Every single version of the overture I've ever listened to sounds like the triple meter version to me (also note the sharp contrast in the melody's implied meter to the meter of the "Ha ha" passage just before), including the Bernstein-conducted version(s). Even when I try humming the passage with the overture's measures' meter accents, the melody sounds like it's fighting against them (especially around "the dreadful" portion and later).

@Dekkadeci well I first heard the overture when I was in my teens, before my rhythmic sense (and for that matter harmonic and contrapuntal) was fully developed, so the tune, by far the loudest thing going on at that point, may have been the only thing I heard.  Similarly, there are several songs that I have heard in middle age after not having heard them since middle school, and I have had the odd experience of recognizing as definitely the same song -- indeed, the same recording -- but perceiving almost all details of the arrangement as if for the first time.

Don't know about this particular example, but the idea of changing time signatures is to get the right emphases on the right notes. This may well entail looking at the words, and making sure that the emphasised words fall on the first beats of certain bars. Especially when the narrative isn't regular.
It could be done this way, or another: write it all in the same time signature, but put accent marks on the words/notes concerned. Either way, the result will be pretty well the same, as your muso stated. It's just a matter of which the writer considered the best/easiest to read.
Seasoned musos are happy to count different bar lengths, just as they are applying accents to notes in odd places, which the alternative would mean doing.

This is an ambiguous sounding figure. I'd consider the score to indicate the intent of the music.  Or perhaps it was notated in 4/4 because the bass already suggests 3/4, so notating it in 3/4 might make it seem like it's intended to be 3/4 when it's actually intended to be ambiguous.  Hearing it in 3/4 does not indicate that something is wrong with your intuition.
Additionally, listen to when the chord changes, and how it relates to the beginning of the bar in each possible way of notating.
